# Proper Caching Strategy for a Dynamic Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

Probably an obvious question for those of you who have scaled/cached anything before. I haven't, and I'm getting lost in the tutorials and code snippets all over the internet (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

I'm deploying to Heroku with Memcached installed and am figuring out the most optimized way to do the following:

1. Query the database to find a post and see if it has been 'flagged'
2. Query a Whitelist to see if a different part of the post has been 'flagged'
3. Query an API to see if they find this user in their system
4. Render a page with a lot of repetitive calls to remote systems for CSS/JS/etc.

I assume #1 happens frequently and changes often. #2 less so. #3 changes infrequently (months), and #4 should only change if #3 changes.

I want to be able to increment flag_count and view_count regularly without hitting a cached version. What mix of page, action and fragment caching should I be doing? Right now, I'm not caching this action at all...

My [simplified] controller code:

```
def show
  expires_in 12.hours, :public => true

  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  #CHECK FLAG STATUS
  redirect_to root_path and return if @post.flag?

  #CHECK WHITELIST STATUS
  redirect_to root_path and return if Whitelist.includes?(@post.screen_name)

  #Ping API again on the off chance user deleted/changed account
  if @post && @post.user = get_user_from_api( @post.screen_name )
    @post.increment_views!
    render :layout => false
  else
    redirect_to root_path
  end    
end
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but my approach to caching during development is to do as little of it as possible while simply commenting spots I come across which will likely require it. I find that I almost always get some unexpected behaviour (because I forgot how I cached something) when I go to production due to early optimization. Once I'm getting close to launch I'll grep for my caching TODO comments and start with fragment caching + cache keys (object id + updated_at) and work my way up from there. I'd say your #3 is a candidate for caching. but implement it close to launch so you remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few small things that might work with this. Tricky given there's no way to avoid hitting the app stack each request.

### Fragment Caching

Use [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) with memcache to avoid regenerating post/comment content. There might be some gains here if your views are heavy. Memcache objects self-expire and can be keyed to the most recent version of a post with something like:

```
<% cache @post.cache_key do %>
  <%= @post.formatted_content %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

### Other things to consider

- Setup server to send cache headers with images, JS & CSS
- Check out [barista](https://github.com/Sutto/barista) to reduce requests & bundle assets